# How to redirect keycloak to a specific IDP when multiple IDPs are configured? kc_idp_hint

Tags: browser, keycloak, hint, idp

I would like a webbrowser user to be forwarded to the Keycloak account console via a specific IDP login, not showing the login browser page.

The keycloak url is https://id.spreitzer.ch

For example logging in via google:

- https://google.id.spreitzer.ch -> general form https://`<idp>`.id.spreitzer.ch

What url should I forward browser users to?

I tried configuring the `kc_idp_hint` parameter, which did not work. For example:

- `htttps://id.spreitzer.ch/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https://xxx&response_type=code&scope=openid&kc_idp_hint=google`

Comment: You should be using a different realm that master for this. Which error are you getting the url seems to be correct

Comment: @dreamcrash Why should I be using a different realm and what difference would that make? There is no error presente, the keycloak login form loads instead of the preferred idp.

Comment: I dont think that in this case it would make any difference. If you read the keycloak official documentation, thetmre they recommend using the master only for administrative related tasks, not to encapsulate the clients and users of your organisation. The url format looks correct, did you try create a manual idp and use its alias as the kc_idp_hint as see if it works?